# I want to write the following code in GAWK?

Tags: python-2.7, gawk

The following code is given in python.I want it to write in gawk but i am unable to find proper link for the syntax.please help me.

```
t=0;
while(t<10):
    x=1
    s = raw_input()
    for c in s:
        if(c=='F' or c=='L' or c=='D' or c=='T'):
            x = x*2
    print x
    t = t+1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
gawk 'NR <= 10 { x=1; len = length($0);
                 for (i = 1; i < len; i++)
                     if (substr($0, i, 1) ~ /[FLDT]/)
                         x *= 2;
                 print x
               }'
```

Untested, therefore probably not quite correct.  The `substr` line is the most likely problem line; it extracts one character at a time from `$0` (hardly the epitome of efficiency) and then compares it with the regex.  You could consider `n = gsub(/[FLDT]/, 'X')` which gives a count of the substitutions it makes (and hence of the number of `[FLDT]` characters in the line) and then multiply `x` appropriately.

The `NR <= 10` condition deals with the first ten lines only.